# Selectively discarding pixels based on background color with shader, Unity + ARFoundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, augmented-reality

I have a problem that I'm finding hard to find a solution to so far... I'm also new to shaders and less new to Unity, so that probably doesn't help.

**I am using AR Foundation to create an application. The application uses the camera image as a background texture. Objects in view should generally be rendered normally, but depending on the color of the camera image being rendered to the background, need to be discarded.** Example: the color of the pixel in the background exceeds a certain blue value, so the object in the foreground does not render that pixel.

My approach so far has been to attempt stencil testing.

I've tried altering the AR Foundation default background shader. I've managed to do basic stuff, like set color values for the fragment before it is returned, so I assumed I could use GLES3 functions like glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST) to enable stencil testing. This prevents rendering all together, so I assume I can't use the full GLES3 functionality.

Using HLSL stencil testing outside the GLSLPROGRAM block works fine, but I cant figure out how to selectively chose ref values based on fragment color rendered in the GLSLPROGRAM block.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm attempting here?

This is the state of the shader currently (this is basically still the default ARCameraBackground shader, uncommenting

`//glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);`

causes errors. Uncommenting:

```
        //Stencil
        //{
        //    Ref 2
        //    Comp Always
        //    Pass Replace
        //}
```

works fine and lets me fully hide or fully show objects with shaders that stencil test as well):

````
Shader "CustomARCoreBackground"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CutoffThresh("CutoffValue", Float) = 0.5
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Background"
            "RenderType" = "Background"
            "ForceNoShadowCasting" = "True"
        }

        Pass
        {
            Cull Off
            ZTest Always
            ZWrite On
            Lighting Off
            LOD 100
            Tags
            {
                "LightMode" = "Always"
            }

            GLSLPROGRAM

#pragma only_renderers gles3

#ifdef SHADER_API_GLES3
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require
#endif // SHADER_API_GLES3

            // Device display transform is provided by the AR Foundation camera background renderer.
            uniform mat4 _UnityDisplayTransform;

#ifdef VERTEX
            varying vec2 textureCoord;

            void main()
            {
#ifdef SHADER_API_GLES3
                // Transform the position from object space to clip space.
                gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

                // Remap the texture coordinates based on the device rotation.
                textureCoord = (_UnityDisplayTransform * vec4(gl_MultiTexCoord0.x, 1.0f - gl_MultiTexCoord0.y, 1.0f, 0.0f)).xy;
#endif // SHADER_API_GLES3
            }
#endif // VERTEX

#ifdef FRAGMENT
            varying vec2 textureCoord;
            uniform samplerExternalOES _MainTex;
            //added threshold variable
            uniform float _CutoffThresh;

#if defined(SHADER_API_GLES3) && !defined(UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA)
            float GammaToLinearSpaceExact (float value)
            {
                if (value <= 0.04045F)
                    return value / 12.92F;
                else if (value < 1.0F)
                    return pow((value + 0.055F)/1.055F, 2.4F);
                else
                    return pow(value, 2.2F);
            }

            vec3 GammaToLinearSpace (vec3 sRGB)
            {
                // Approximate version from http://chilliant.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/srgb-approximations-for-hlsl.html?m=1
                return sRGB * (sRGB * (sRGB * 0.305306011F + 0.682171111F) + 0.012522878F);

                // Precise version, useful for debugging, but the pow() function is too slow.
                // return vec3(GammaToLinearSpaceExact(sRGB.r), GammaToLinearSpaceExact(sRGB.g), GammaToLinearSpaceExact(sRGB.b));
            }
#endif // SHADER_API_GLES3 && !UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA

            void main()
            {
                //glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

#ifdef SHADER_API_GLES3
                vec3 result = texture(_MainTex, textureCoord).xyz;

#ifndef UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA
                result = GammaToLinearSpace(result);
#endif // !UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA

                gl_FragColor = vec4(result, 1);
                gl_FragDepth = 1.0f;
#endif // SHADER_API_GLES3
            }

#endif // FRAGMENT


            ENDGLSL

            //Stencil
            //{
            //    Ref 2
            //    Comp Always
            //    Pass Replace
            //}
        }
    }
    FallBack Off
}```
````